# How to put an image at the top of a video?

Tags: html, css

I need to put an image at the top of a video like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmMOW.png)

This is my code

```html
  <video class = "video-hero" autoplay autoplay muted loop id= "video-hero">
             <img src=Geo-caching.png
      width="140" 
     height="140">
        <source src="//d17wd0umvxxjds.cloudfront.net/play/Content/videos/loggedout-cache-finds.webm">
```

Comment: this should help you out:  [image over video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802183/image-over-a-video-html5)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a poster attribute to your video tag and give it the image you want.
`<video poster = "Geo-caching.png">`

Here is a link you can learn more https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_poster.asp

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by poster attribute in video tag,

```html
<video controls 
               width="400" 
              height="200" 
              poster=
Geo-caching.png>
            <source src=
"//d17wd0umvxxjds.cloudfront.net/play/Content/videos/loggedout-cache-finds.webm" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `video controls poster` attribute. The `poster` gives you a thumbnail for your video, while the `controls` attribute allows for the controls to still be present with the image, so that when the video starts, the image disappears. However, a lot of browsers don't support the video tag. In that case, I would use JavaScript with a `font-awesome` play button to resemble this attribute.

**Note:** In order for this to work, I had to take the `autoplay` attribute off your video.

```html
<video controls poster="https://dummyimage.com/700x400/000/fff"  class="video-hero" muted loop id= "video-hero">
  <source src="//d17wd0umvxxjds.cloudfront.net/play/Content/videos/loggedout-cache-finds.webm" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```